# R programming and how to separate positive and negative values in a vector

Tags: r

If there are two values positive and negative values in a vector how to take only the positive values in that vector or else how to take only negative values in that vector

For example :
vector <- c(140, -50, 20, -120, 240)

The negative values corresponds to losses and positive values corresponds to winning and  I suppose to add all the winnings alone in that vector.
How to solve this.

Comment: Use `vector[vector>0]` and `vector[vector<0]` to extract the positive and negative numbers, respectively.

Comment: [`?ifelse`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html)`(vector < 0, 0, vector)` and [`?pmax`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extremes.html)`(0, vector)` come to mind as additional methods, though @ekstroem's suggestion is the most direct.

Comment: `vector[vector > 0]` for positive and `vector[vector<0]` for negative

Answer (score 1):

Subsetting a vector is as easy as shown by @ekstroem. If you want to sum over, say, all positive values in your vector, you could simply do

```
   sum(vector[vector>0])
```